# How to update values in dataframe based on a two-column lookup

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing three columns of interest. I'm trying to fill in values in one column, based on the other **two** columns of information.

The equivalent in Excel would be to concatenate "Country" and "Service" into another column on the lookup table, then do a vlookup on these columns concatenated on the live data. Translating this into Python/Pandas is proving tricky

From looking up other similar answers (the only ones I've found only pertain to single-column lookups) using `.apply` and defining a function seems to be where I need to go. I'm struggling to interpret how this works, though. Or would it make more sense to stick the look-up table into a multi-level dictionary of some sort?

Initial Dataframe:

```
    Price   Country Service
0   0   GB  A
1   0   FR  A
2   0   FR  A
3   0   GB  B
4   0   GB  B
5   0   FR  B
6   0   GB  C
7   0   GB  C
```

Lookup:

```
Country Service Price
GB  A   0.1
FR  A   0.2
GB  B   0.8
FR  B   1.2
GB  C   0.5
FR  C   0.2
```

Resulting DataFrame:

```
    Price   Country Service
0   0.1 GB  A
1   0.2 FR  A
2   0.2 FR  A
3   0.8 GB  B
4   0.8 GB  B
5   1.2 FR  B
6   0.5 GB  C
7   0.5 GB  C
```

Comment: You want a left merge `df.merge(lookup, on=['Country', 'Service'], how='left')`

Comment: Ah, amazing. Thank you! Like a join in SQL. I was completely missing the "merge" keyword here. Seeing as the answer effectively exists elsewhere - do I need to edit my question or mark it as "answered"?

Comment: No, its fine, having set it as a dupe is enough. You're welcome :)